# Amortized analysis on skew heap arbitrary deletion

Tags: graphs, heaps, amortized-analysis

A practice problem in my textbook asks to proof the amortized complexity for a sequence of insert, delete min, and decrease-key operations on an initially empty skew heap. Insert and delete min both have an amortized complexity of $O(log(n))$, and the deletion algorithm that removes an arbitrary node in a skew heap is defined as:

The subtree $ S_v $ with root $v$ is removed from the heap. Then the path from $v$ to the root (of the tree) is traversed. If a vertex on that path has $v$ in its left subtree and has a right child, then its children are swapped. This way the result remains a skew heap. The root of $ S_v $ is removed by the delete min operation, the left and right subtree of $v$ get merged, and that result gets merged with the initial tree.

I get that I'll have to use either the potential method or the accounting method, and I use the definitions for heavy and light edges (the original paper about skew heaps uses this definition for nodes instead):

"Take any node $v$ with its child $c$; we call the edge from $v$ to $c$ heavy, if size of $c$’s subtree is more than half the size of $v$’s subtree, or in other words, more than half of the descendants of $v$ are under $c$ . Otherwise we call the edge ($v$,$c$) light."

I don't really get how I should account for the traversal from $v$ to the root that takes place during the arbitrary deletion algorithm in my analysis though.